# How to do value matching for a date object?

Tags: r, lubridate

Should I always do value matching for a date object indirectly, via `as.character()` or `as.numeric()`, or is there a robust way to check date objects themselves?

I have a few datasets where some date variables were unfortunately filled in with filler values -- and it's not the same filler value everywhere. I need to turn these to true NA's. Here are my filler values:

```
# Filler dates: the kind that should be missing
datefiller <- as.POSIXct(c('1899-12-30', 
                           '1900-01-01'), 
                         tz = 'MST')
```

So, the check below should return a TRUE, shouldn't it?

```
> as.Date('1899-12-30') %in% datefiller
[1] FALSE
```

I mean, if I checked with a `==` instead, I would get the expected result:

```
> as.Date('1899-12-30') == datefiller
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Put another way, the tibble below should have two TRUE and two FALSE values in the second column, but they're all FALSE, and I have no idea why:

```
tibble(badandgooddates = c(as.Date('1899-12-30'), 
                           as.Date('1900-01-01'), 
                           Sys.Date(), 
                           as.Date('1776-07-04'))) %>% 
mutate(isbad = badandgooddates %in% datefiller)
```

Here's what I get:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  badandgooddates isbad
  <date>          <lgl>
1 1899-12-30      FALSE
2 1900-01-01      FALSE
3 2018-05-14      FALSE
4 1776-07-04      FALSE
```

When I force the comparisons to character strings instead of dates, I get what I expect:

```
> tibble(badandgooddates = c(as.Date('1899-12-30'), 
                             as.Date('1900-01-01'), 
                             Sys.Date(), 
                             as.Date('1776-07-04'))) %>% 
    mutate(isbad = badandgooddates %in% datefiller) %>% 
    mutate(isbadcharacter = as.character(badandgooddates) %in% 
             as.character(datefiller))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  badandgooddates isbad isbadcharacter
  <date>          <lgl> <lgl>         
1 1899-12-30      FALSE TRUE          
2 1900-01-01      FALSE TRUE          
3 2018-05-14      FALSE FALSE         
4 1776-07-04      FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: `Sys.Date() < '2020-01-01'` works, suggesting you can use `character` comparisons when simple, such as LT, GT, LE, GT, etc. Instead of `POSIXt`, you might try `datefiller <- as.Date(...)`, after which your `%in%` should work. (`POSIXt` and `Date` objects do not compare well here ...)

Comment: Reversing the order (and creating datafiller using `as.Date` instead) makes the %in% option work as expected: `datefiller %in% as.Date('1899-12-30') `